# Non negative matrix factorization initial values and final values

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I am planning to use initial values that are {0, 1}. How do we ensure or how does NMF ensure that the final values are also in the [0,1] range.

What if we want to model a matrix of frequencies of connections of two items. Then how do the final values after NMF change, what would their range be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NMF is a constrained minimization (>=0). If you want your values to be between [0,1], then constrain from above as well.

Comment: I am fairly new to this subject. How may I apply a constraint in optimization process? Is there a good source for it?